# Glassfish - VERY strange ClassCastException

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I get this exception when try to call remote web service...
Strange - because we have this exception ONLY in Glassfish 2.1/3.1 environment...
When im start code from command line (JDK 1.6.0_16-b01) all works fine! So looks its a Glassfish problem

Any ideas?

> Task execution failed com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException:
>   HTTP transport error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:131)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:219)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:143)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:139)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:429)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:168)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
>          at $Proxy317.zapCableDevice(Unknown Source)
>          at com.dob.ns.service.ZAPService.authorizeSTB(ZAPService.java:128)
>          at com.dob.ns.service.ZAPService.process(ZAPService.java:91)
>          at com.dob.ns.core.DOBProcessDescriptor$DOBServiceExecutor.run(DOBProcessDescriptor.java:269)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.createHttpConnection(HttpClientTransport.java:287)
>          at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:116)

... 17 more

Problemm ONLY when code called inside deployed EAR

```
        RequestData req = new RequestData();
        String MacAddress = ServiceUtils.formatMac(mac);
        req.setClientSystemId(CLIENT_SYSTEM_ID);
        req.setMacAddress(MacAddress);
        req.setSerialNumber(SerialNumber);

        CableDevicesServicesSoap dev = service.getCableDevicesServicesSoap();
        ZapCableDeviceRequest request = new ZapCableDeviceRequest();
        request.setRequestData(req);
        request.setTransactionId(transactionId);
        ZapCableDeviceResponse answer = dev.zapCableDevice(request);
```

All parameters is String type

Comment: Would be helpful to see the wsdl of the service you're calling, plus you code for calling it, reduced to a SSCCE.

Comment: As im say - its not a code problem , becasue same code works fine fom command line

Comment: Righto. Moving on then...

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34277568/1032484)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. It took me couple of hours to fix the problem. I was using the wrong BindingProviderProperties interface.

The BindingProviderProperties interface exists in two different packages. (for different Java/JAX-WS versions)

If you are getting ClassCastException most probably you need import different package in your soap service class.

change

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties;
```

to

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties;
```